# How to find wifi/cellular signal strength in ios

Tags: ios, wifi, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi

Hi in my application I have to implement two features.

1. Find wifi's available around me and finding those wifi's signal streangth.
2. Find Carrier signal's available around me and finding those signal streanghts.

Can anyone please let me know how can we implement this feature.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Didnt like to ask this...but still people are pushing : what did you try?

Comment: Hi lithu thanks for your reply. i tried and found find wifi signal strength is possible before ios4 not now. I am not sure about cellular signal strength feature.